# How to fix FuncAnimation exception in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My matplotlib script, that runs on Windows, runs two animations:

```
anim = []

anim.append( matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig_ul, updatePlots_ul,frames=None, interval=100, repeat=True) )
anim.append( matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig_dl, updatePlots_dl, frames=None,interval=100, repeat=True) )

plt.show()      # line 476
```

When I terminate the script by closing one of the figures I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpClient.py", line 476, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 253, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 163, in __call__
manager.show()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 610, in show
self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes'
```

How could I improve my code to avoid this untidy exception?

**Update: Addition of Minimum, verifiable example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

def _updateSubplot(sc):
    i_data = [1,2]
    q_data = [1,2]
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[i_data, q_data])

# Create figure A and subplots

fig_A, axarr_A = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))

x_data = []
y_data = []

sc_A_1 = axarr_A[0,0].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)
sc_A_2 = axarr_A[0,1].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)
sc_A_5 = axarr_A[1,0].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)
sc_A_6 = axarr_A[1,1].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)

fig_A.tight_layout()

# Create figure B and subplots

fig_B, axarr_B = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(3, 6))

x_data = []
y_data = []

sc_B_1 = axarr_B[0].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)
sc_B_2 = axarr_B[1].scatter(x_data, y_data, c='r', s=4)

fig_B.tight_layout()

# Animation functions

def updatePlots_A(i):
    _updateSubplot(sc_A_1)

def updatePlots_B(i):
    _updateSubplot(sc_B_1)
    _updateSubplot(sc_B_2)


anim = [] # List of Animation objects for tracking

anim.append( matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig_A, updatePlots_A, frames=None, interval=100, repeat=True) )
anim.append( matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig_B, updatePlots_B, frames=None, interval=100, repeat=True) )

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this issue requires to provide a [mcve]. Otherwise noone can reproduce it and hence it's difficult to help.

Comment: I have added such an example.

Comment: I can run the example and close the figures without problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me which Python and matplotlib versions you are using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.0.2 on windows 8.1. However, I think it is more important that you tell everyone what system you are using here.

Comment: Sorry, Python 3.6.1, matplotlib 2.0.2 on Windows 10.